# How to set up jenkins server to use a proxy certificate using docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, certificate

I've stood up a jenkins instance using docker and the jenkins/jenkins image (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins).  I'm working behind a corporate proxy that requires a cert (zscaler).

How can I configure jenkins to look for an proxy certificate?  Or, if there is a standard location where jenkins will look for certs, what is that location?

Please let me know if there is a more appropriate forum for this question.